# load url in UIWebView by POSTing username and password?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, http-post, nsmutableurlrequest

I'm trying to load a website in UIWebView by automatically login to that website. I'm posting username and password . It loads the website but not logged in. The login not working. any idea?

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.abc.com"];

        NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"login_name=%@&login_password=%@&submit=Login", @"abc", @"abc"];
        NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
        NSLog(@"POST Length = %@",postLength);
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
        [request setURL:url];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];
        [request setTimeoutInterval:5.0];
         [webView loadRequest:request];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just built a sample app with my code to load a webview.  I call a specific page in my form submission and it works to login to the web service.  I am posting the code here:

```
NSString *username = @"abc";
NSString *password = @"abc";
NSString *postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@",username, password];
NSLog(@"%@", postString);
NSData *postData = [postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.someurl.com/loginscript"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

Maybe this code will help you.

Comment: It wont make any difference. Just check it.

Comment: Ok...Sorry. I use posts all the time and they work great.  I will post my sample code.

Comment: I have changed my answer to use a login script to call a webView.

Comment: Ok.  Does the webpage you're referencing have a specific form on it for login? If so, you can get the directing page by viewing the source of the page and checking the <form action="loginscript" method="post">.  If there is a page in the action then that is the page you need to put in your URL.  Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Try taking SUBMIT out of your postString.  I don't know what could be going on. I've got my application logging in this way just fine.

Comment: I completely changed my answer to include the login code for the site. Is this a php site you are trying to connect to?

Comment: What is the form action on that php page?

Answer (score 1):

Could it be failing because you're missing a semicolon between `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `charset=utf-8`?

Try `application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8` and see if that helps.

Comment: Are you sure the site uses UTF-8? Have you tried switching to `NSASCIIStringEncoding` and removing `;charset=UTF-8` altogether? You might want to use a proxy like [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com) to capture the proper request format & headers.

Comment: Pls check it.

(Request-Line) POST /login.cgi HTTP/1.1
Host xyz:abc

Accept text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Connection keep-alive
Referer http://xyz:abc/
Cookie testing=1
Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length 29